# How to make DWR Session invalid in network crash?

Tags: session, dwr

I am using dwr for sending UI updates every 10 seconds for some UI action.
The push of updates will be stopped when there is a deregister from UI.
Now when there is a network crash or any other error scenerio, there wont be a deregister from UI.

In these scenerios,How the server knows and stop updates to that particular UI.

I tried checking the session validation in the following way.If the session is null then the updates wont be sent.

```
Container container = ServerContextFactory.get().getContainer();
    ScriptSessionManager manager = container.getBean(ScriptSessionManager.class);
    for( ScriptSession sessions:manager.getAllScriptSessions()){
       if( sessionId.equals(sessions.getId()))
           return sessions;
    }
    return null;
}
```

But in the network crash scenerio, the session is not null and deregister is not happenning.